# Unable to Hide anchor tag using display property

Tags: html, css

While working on a web page with prettyPhoto plugin to display the image gallery, I need to add the hyperlinks to pictures which are shown in the gallery section. But these hyperlinks result in blank space under the image responsible to initiate the gallery.

Demo code as given below.

```
 <div class="folio-image">
          <a href="images/slider/coverimage.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]"><div class="overShadow"></div><h3>Slider title</h3><img src="images/slider/image1.jpg" class="img-responsive max-400" /></a>
          <a href="images/slider/31.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery3]" width="0" height="0" display="none !important" ><img src="images/slider/31.jpg" width="0" height="0" display="none !important" /></a>
</div>
```

In the above code the `Folio-image` div denotes the section that holds the image responsible to load the gallery popup. The `overShadow` is used to show the text on the image.The first `a` tag denotes the image that is responsible for initiating the gallery popup.The anchor tags that follow later are referring to the other images included in the slider.I need to hide the blank space occupied by these anchor tags.Already tried the `display="none"` also marked the same as `important` which also did not seem to work.How can I fix this?

Comment: `display="none !important"` has to be `style="display:none !important"`

Comment: @Roberrrt tried this but does not seem to work.

Comment: Then i'm assuming your problem doesn't lie with the `display:none`

Comment: So is there a way by which  I can prevent 'a' tags from resulting into the blank space in the webpage ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this or please post a working example/screenshot

```
<div class="folio-image">
    <a href="images/slider/coverimage.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">
      <div class="overShadow"></div>
      <h3>Slider title</h3>

      <img src="images/slider/image1.jpg" class="img-responsive max-400" />
    </a>
    <a href="images/slider/31.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery3]" width="0" height="0" style="display:none; visibility: hidden;">
      <img src="images/slider/31.jpg"" width="0" height="0" style="display:none; visibility: hidden;"/>
    </a>
</div>
```